# Need help debugging this code in Matlab

Tags: arrays, debugging, matlab, cell, combinations

I have the following code

```
B=[1 2 3; 10 20 30 ; 100 200 300 ; 500 600 800];
A=[100; 500; 300 ; 425];
SA = sum(A);
V={}; % number of rows for cell V = num of combinations -- column = 1                
n = 1;
 arr =  zeros(1,length(B))
for k = 1:length(B)                    
    for idx = nchoosek(1:numel(B), k)'  
       rows = mod(idx, length(B))
       if ~isequal(rows, unique(rows)) %if rows not equal to unique(rows)
           continue  %combination possibility valid      
       end %Ignore the combination if there are two elements from the same row 
       B_subset = B(idx)
       if (SA + sum(B_subset) <= 3000) %if sum of A + (combination) < 3000
           rows( rows==0 )=4
           arr(rows) = B_subset(:)
           V(n,1) = {arr}
           n = n + 1
            arr =  zeros(1,length(B))
        end
    end
end
```

The combinations are supposed to be valid if the sum of A and some values of B are less than 3000.

Problem with my code is, the last value of B, `B(3,3)`, is only accounted for once in the code.

If you run the code, you will notice one cell of `V` containing `[0;0;0;800]` at row 12. But there are other combinations possible as well such as `[1;0;0;800]`. Where `SA + (1 + 800) < 3000` , however the code does not print this possibility.

I cannot figure out why, can someone please help me debug this and find out why some combinations are skipped ? especially `B(3,3)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that this line is not doing exactly what you intended:

```
if ~isequal(rows, unique(rows))
```

Instead, try this:

```
if ~isequal(length(rows), length(unique(rows)))
```

Comment: Oh perfect .. its 7am and I've been working on the code since 6pm .. so no wonder I missed that !! haha good eye, thank you very much. Now I can get some sleep.

Comment: Can you just quickly tell me why did this fix the problem btw ?

Comment: try this: a = [1 1 3 5] and then unique(a). you will get ans = [1 3 5]. So, basically unique() returns only the unique elements in a sorted manner. So, when you were passing combinations like [2 0], unique() was returning [0 2] the if statement would be true(falsely :P)